# How to make Alexa Skill reach internal network devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, alexa-skills-kit

I've developed an Alexa for business skill which connects to some of our local devices and performs several tasks on them. During development, I gave several of these devices public IP addresses so that they could be accessed by AWS. However, I would like for AWS to be able to connect to them when they are within our LAN. I was thinking that the connection could be made through a VPN, though I do not know whether this is possible or a good idea. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this by using [AWS Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/), however there are some limitations as your network must be able to connect to a Direct Connect location. See this guide for more info: https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/getting-started/

There are also options for using a VPN as you suggest: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html

And finally you might be able to use something like [Localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) or ngrok.com, but this would require opening ports on your private network.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, it's best to avoid making connections back into your network and instead get the devices to poll out of your network to receive instructions.

Depending on what the devices are, you might want to consider using [AWS IoT](https://aws.amazon.com/iot) as a mechanism for connecting the devices to a control plane in AWS. That control plane could comprise either [device shadows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html) for each device (if device state management is important), or an [MQTT message broker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-message-broker.html) (if simple messaging is required).

Can you explain a bit more about what the tasks are and what the devices are?